# Save image to SQL Server database using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I use this code for saving an image in database. The code runs without any error but does not save data in my database:

```
    var db = new AlmostafaDataLinqDataContext();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    fs.Close();
    db.pEditImage(RecordID, data);
```

and this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pEditImage 
    @ID int, @Image image
AS
    UPDATE Reshteh_Data 
    SET Meyvast_image = @Image
    WHERE ID = @ID

    RETURN
```

MY Data Base Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reshteh_Data] (
    [ID]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ReshtehName]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [Maghta]        NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [MA_Date]       NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [MV_Date]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Country]       NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [M_Country]     NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [Meyvast_image] IMAGE          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Is there are a row in your database table for the `@ID`  value you're  passing in?

Comment: yes exactly , I have ID row is primary key

Comment: You should not be using the `IMAGE` datatype (same with `TEXT` and `NTEXT`) unless you are still on SQL Server 2000. Those 3 were deprecated in SQL Server 2005. Please use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead (and likewise for those other two: `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, respectively).

Comment: I test varbinary but not save data in field again

Answer (score 0):

You never handled IDisposible correctly, did not save your changes and using a file stream is needlessly complex. Try this:

```
using(var db = new AlmostafaDataLinqDataContext())
{
    byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
    db.pEditImage(RecordID, data);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: And the ID you pass in is an ID that already exists in your database?

Comment: code run without error and create byte array  but not insert in DB

Comment: How did you *check* that it was not inserted? Where is your DB, what was your tool?

Comment: I see Data DB in Visual studio server explorer

Comment: @m.h.bayan Is your database local?